# move_base warning sensor out of bounds

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up the navigation stack to work on a differential drive mobile platform (the Pekee 2 robot by Wany) and I'm having issues to make it work.

I've already followed the steps in the tutorial in http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup to set up the robot, and I've successfully created a map of the environment I want to test it in by using the slam_gmapping node.

However, when I run the whole thing, the move_base node keeps outputting a warning that says

```
[ WARN] [1304077069.890195016]: The origin for the sensor at (0.42, -0.22, 0.23) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
[ WARN] [1304077070.090216854]: The origin for the sensor at (0.43, -0.24, 0.23) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
[ WARN] [1304077070.290202557]: The origin for the sensor at (0.46, -0.28, 0.23) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
[ WARN] [1304077070.490195304]: The origin for the sensor at (0.47, -0.29, 0.23) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
[ WARN] [1304077070.690157122]: The origin for the sensor at (0.48, -0.30, 0.23) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
[ WARN] [1304077070.890200670]: The origin for the sensor at (0.51, -0.31, 0.23) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
[ WARN] [1304077071.090191993]: The origin for the sensor at (0.52, -0.31, 0.23) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
```

(I put several lines to note that the sensor origin changes at the robot spins, in case it's important)

In addition, when I try to send a goal the robot starts spinning around and an additional warning which says

```
[ WARN] [1304077075.656158292]: The robot's start position is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail, are you sure the robot has been properly localized?
```

Until it stops with an error

```
[ERROR] [1304077075.706049498]: Aborting because a valid plan could not be found. Even after executing all recovery behaviors
```

The thing is that using rviz, after setting up the initial pose, the robot footprint is fully inside the map, as well as the whole pose array cloud in the /particlecloud topic (after teleoperating the robot around for a while).

Can anyone help me with this? I'll try to get more insight of how the navigation stack works, but I'd really like to have something working even before knowing what exactly is going on because of deadline issues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9845/move_base-warning-sensor-out-of-bounds/) by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1071 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-29**:
There is probably problem with your localization. Global costmap uses map from map server for it's costmap. When you haven't localized properly your robot, robot might get outside your map borders and then you receive and error. There might be also a problem with your transformations. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Miguel,

It seems that the transform between the /map frame and the /odom frame works fine for you. From the warning you get I would say that you have some configuration parameters of the costmaps that are not set correctly. The move_base node uses two costmaps, the local costmap and the global costmap. If you are using a map, make sure to configure the global costmap as static map. However, the local one should not be static (look at the rolling_window parameter). You can find all the parameters at http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d

I hope this can help you!

---

Originally posted by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) with karma: 219 on 2011-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-04-29**:
Hi gazkune. It was indeed a problem with the costmap configuration parameters. Few days ago I was trying to run the navigation without using a map, and I must have changed the static map parameter to false in the global costmap yaml back then. It was quite a stupid mistake after all. Thanks.

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-12-01**:
I am confused, When I run the navigation without using a map, Should I set "static_map" true or false in the global costmap yaml?

**Comment by [peterwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28779/peterwe/) on 2017-04-13**:
When you run the navigation stack without a prior map, you should set "static_map: true". This means that the map does not get updated over time.

**Comment by [jinseoi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32501/jinseoi/) on 2017-11-05**:
Actually, you can set "static_map: false", and set global_map as a rolling window like what you set parameter for local_map. Navigation without a prior map will also work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reply the same problem at here: [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/45976/how-to-configure-the-map-to-put-its-origin-as-in-stage/?answer=347254#post-id-347254)
This answer is the same with link.

Hi there,

I met the same problem today, and I solved this problem.

1. Open global_costmap_params.yaml
2. Add below statement

> rolling_window: true

Example in my global_costmap_params.yaml:

> global_costmap:    global_frame: /map
> robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
> update_frequency: 1.0
> publish_frequency: 0.5    static_map:
> true    transform_tolerance: 0.5
> rolling_window: true
> plugins:
> - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
> - {name: obstacle_layer,          type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
> - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

I hope this way also effective in your project!

---

Originally posted by [Kyuhwan Yeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/52761/kyuhwan-yeon/) with karma: 23 on 2020-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lgaraffa](https://answers.ros.org/users/114866/lgaraffa/) on 2022-08-20**:
It worked for me! Thankssss